# Comparing smaller registers in assembly code

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, nasm, cpu-registers

I have written a simple assembly program that reads in two bytes from the keyboard. The program compares the bytes and prints out which is larger or equal if they are equal.

I am using a 64 bit machine, with 8 byte registers and I believe memory is 8 bytes as wide as well.

My question is, how do I just use 8 bits in a register rather than all 64 bits? Currently in order to perform what I want, I have to clear all 64 bits in a register with an `xor   rax, rax` instruction or `mov  rax, 0` instruction. It would be easier if I could just load the 8 bits I want to compare and perform my `sub` operation on those 8 bits.

```
     global      _start

            section     .text
_start:                  
            push        0
            mov         rbp,rsp
            sub         rsp,0x10

            ;Clear out contents
            xor         rax,rax
            mov         [rbp-0x8],rax
            mov         [rbp-0x10],rax

            push        intro
            push        0x42
            call        print

            mov         rax, 0
            mov         rdi, 0
            lea         rsi, [rbp-0x8]
            mov         rdx, 2
            syscall

            mov         rax, 0
            mov         rdi, 0
            lea         rsi, [rbp-0x10]
            mov         rdx, 2
            syscall



            mov         rax, [rbp-0x8]
            mov         rbx, [rbp-0x10]
            sub         rax,rbx
            je          equal
            jg          firstlarger
            jl          secondlarger
equal:            
            push        equalmessage
            push        0xfg
            call        print
            jmp         exit
firstlarger:
            push        first
            push        0x10
            call        print
            jmp         exit
secondlarger:
            push        second
            push        0x11
            call        print
            jmp         exit

exit:
            mov         rax,60
            xor         rdi,rdi
            syscall

print:
            push        rbp
            mov         rbp,rsp
            sub         rsp,0x0

            mov         rax,1
            mov         rdi,1
            mov         rsi, [rbp+0x18]
            mov         rdx, [rbp+0x10]
            syscall
            leave
            ret         0x10

            section     .data
intro:      db          "Please enter 1 character, hit enter, then another, then hit enter", 10
equalmessage: db         "They are equal",10
first:      db          "First is larger",10
second:     db          "Second is larger",10
```

Comment: You still have all the 8, 16 and 32 bit registers. Hell, you even have new ones. Consult a basic architecture manual. E.g. `cmp al, bl` is entirely legal even in 64 bit mode.

Comment: Do you have a link to a basic architecture manual?

Comment: [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual Volume 1, Basic Architecture](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/processors/pentium4/sb/25366521.pdf) Section 3.4.1.1 General-Purpose Registers in 64-Bit Mode, Table 3-2. Addressable General Purpose Registers

Comment: [This MASM tutorial](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html) is by 70-80% directly usable with NASM too, and I like how it is structured and quite short, but still has reasonable amount of detail and accuracy, unfortunately it is 32 bit only (but the way how 32 bit mode uses 16 and 8 bit registers is same for 64 bit mode). ... try it as additional simplified resource (the Intel manuals are much better in case you need full information, but may be a bit too large for quick start).